# How to write a SQL query that creates a separate column for each possible value of a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

Sorry - this is a probably a trivially simple SQL question, but I couldn't figure out how to write a Google search to get what I needed.

I have a table that looks like this:

```
id   color  points
---  -----  ------
  1  red        10
  2  blue       20
  3  blue       30
  4  red       100
  5  blue       70
  6  blue      200
  7  red        30
```

I would like to know 2 things:

1. How many rows have color='red', and how many have color='blue'?
2. What is the total number of points for rows with color='red', and color='blue'?

Using `count()`, `sum()`, and `group by`, I can easily create a result set that looks like this:

```
select
    color,
    count(color),
    sum(points)
from
    my_table
group by
    color

color  count  points
-----  -----  ------
red        3     140
blue       4     320
```

However, what I really want is one row of results that looks like this:

```
red_count  red_points  blue_count  blue_points
---------  ----------  ----------  -----------
        3         140           4          320
```

For what it's worth - my ideal query doesn't need to be flexible to handle an undetermined number of different colors; I'm 100% OK assuming that there are always, and only, two colors.

Also - in this instance, I'm using SQL Server, and I'm ok if the solution uses something specific to that. (Of course, a generic SQL solution would be even better...)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this generic query :

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN color='red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) red_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN color='red' THEN points ELSE 0 END) red_points
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN color='blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blue_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN color='blue' THEN points ELSE 0 END) blue_points
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) red_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'red' THEN points ELSE 0 END) red_points,
        SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) blue_count,
        SUM(CASE WHEN color = 'Blue' THEN points ELSE 0 END) blue_points
FROM    tableName
```

Comment: JW - thanks for a great answer! Looks like you, XLAnt, and JW all came up with the same answer; if you don't mind, i'm going to get the checkmark to XLAnt because it looks like you need the points less than him/her. Let me know if that's not fair.

Answer (score 3):

You can *pivot* the data using an aggregate and a `CASE` expression:

```
select
  sum(case when color = 'red' then 1 else 0 end) red_count,
  sum(case when color = 'red' then points end) red_points,
  sum(case when color = 'blue' then 1 else 0 end) blue_count,
  sum(case when color = 'blue' then points end) blue_points
from my_table
```

Comment: bluefeet - thanks for a great answer! Looks like you, XLAnt, and JW all came up with the same answer; if you don't mind, i'm going to get the checkmark to XLAnt because it looks like you need the points less than him/her. Let me know if that's not fair.

Comment: @mattstuehler that is totally fair! :)